# APScheduler add lots of jobs concurrently (database Jobstore)

Tags: python-3.x, concurrency, python-asyncio, apscheduler

How can I schedule lots of APScheduler jobs (4,000+) concurrently? (I must schedule all these after certain user events.)

Iteratively calling `add_job` simply takes too long with many jobs. But when I try to use `AsyncIOScheduler` and the following async code, I don't get any added performance increase either.

*NOTE: my scheduler needs to connect to a SQL jobstore via SqlAlchemy*

```
scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler(jobstores={"default": SQLAlchemyJobStore(url="a valid db connection str")})
scheduler.start()

def schedule_jobs_quickly():
    # init lots of (fake) jobs
    jobs = []
    for i in range(3000):
        jobs.append(i)
    send_time = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=2)

    # try to schedule jobs concurrently
    start_time = time.time()
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(schedule_all_jobs(jobs, send_time))
    duration = time.time() - start_time
    print(f"Created {len(jobs)} jobs in {duration} seconds")


async def schedule_all_jobs(all_jobs, send_time):
    tasks = []
    for job in all_jobs:
        task = asyncio.ensure_future(schedule_job(job, send_time))
        tasks.append(task)
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)


async def schedule_job(job, send_time):
    scheduler.add_job(send_email_if_needed, trigger=send_time)
```

**Result is very slow. How to speed this up?**

```
>>> schedule_jobs_quickly()
...
Created 3000 jobs in 401.9982771873474 seconds
```

For comparison, this is how long it took with a `BackgroundScheduler()` using the default memory jobstore:

```
Created 3000 jobs in 0.9155495166778564 seconds
```

So, it seems to be the database connections that are so expensive. Maybe there's a way to create multiple jobs using the same connection, instead of re-connecting for each `add_job`?

Answer (score 1):

It's not the solution I was looking for, but I decided to give up on AsyncIOScheduler and instead schedule my many tasks in a separate thread so the rest of my program could continue without being held up by all of the DB connections. Example below.

```py
from threading import Thread

def schedule_jobs_quickly():
    # init lots of (fake) jobs
    jobs = []
    for i in range(3000):
        jobs.append(i)
    send_time = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=2)

    # schedule jobs in new thread
    scheduler_thread = Thread(target=schedule_email_jobs, args=(email_jobs,))
    scheduler_thread.start()


def schedule_email_jobs(jobs):
    for job in jobs:
        scheduler.add_job(send_email, trigger=send_time)

def send_email():
   # sends email
```

Comment: What type of speed did you get?

Comment: I don't remember, sorry